# How can I generate a dataset to test variable importance calculations?

Tags: dataset, random-generation, importance

I would like to generate random data that has predetermined variable importance, so that I can test out different methods of calculating variable importance and see how they perform vs. the predetermined.

The model consists of:

- Ratings being given on a scale from 1-5 which follow an approximate normal distribution (the ratings are all in the same scale).
- Each variable in the model represents the person's satisfaction with something about a product and the outcome variable represents the person's overall satisfaction with the product (which they rate separately).
- Questions are correlated with each other, with correlations as high as 0.7

I would like to measure importance as how much each variable is able to predict the outcome variable. In other words, how changing one variable will impact the outcome variable changing also. This would be measured in absolute terms (although I'm open to relative importance also).

In my dataset, I would like to have around 10-15 predictors and an outcome variable, with predictors being correlated (maybe between 0.2-0.7) and a predetermined "rough" importance of each predictor on the outcome. The scale of predictors/outcome would ideally be from 1-5.

I plan on then testing out a few different things:

- Different methods of how to calculate variable importance to see how they stack up against each other
- Reducing the sample size to see how each method performs
- Increasing the number of missing values in the dataset to see how each method performs (after imputing data/complete case analysis)

Comment: For this to be answerable, you need to give us a quantitative definition or formula for "importance:" "determined by me" isn't something we can effectively use to advise you.

Comment: I will specify how "important" each variable is to the outcome variable on a scale from 0-100, and then test this against methods including: Random Forest Variable Importance, Standardized Beta Coefficients from MLR, Partial Least Squares, Johnson’s Relative Weights, proportional marginal variance decomposition, R^2 contribution. I will probably compare based on ranking of variables and relative importance numbers. Unless you have a recommendation on how I should pre-determine importance.

Comment: I cannot recommend anything because you haven't explained what "importance" actually is.

Comment: Importance is how much each variable is able to predict the outcome variable. How changing one variable will impact the outcome variable changing also.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful.  But it needs to be more specific: (1) exactly what is the model? (2) How do you measure "impact" of a change in outcome? (Sometimes it's measured on an absolute scale, other times on a relative scale, and sometimes in other ways.) (3) Because you mention correlations among predictors, do you intend to change them independently or not when assessing importance? (4) How will you determine when two different predictors are changed by equal amounts? E.g., if one is in kilograms and the other in meters, how many kilograms will you equate with how many meters of change?

Comment: (1) The model is ratings being given by people on a scale from 1-5 which follow an approximate normal distribution, the ratings are all in the same scale along with the outcome variable. Each variable represents the person's satisfaction with something about a product and the outcome variable represents the person's overall satisfaction with the product (which they rate separately). Does this help? (2) I think in this case it will be easier to deal with an absolute scale, as opposed to relative - but I'm open to both.

Comment: (3) I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "change them independently". I plan on generating data with predetermined correlations if possible and use that data for all my analyses. (4) All predictors (questions) are in the same scale, so I don't think this will be an issue?

Comment: @whuber I've updated the description and answer your questions above